# How to handle players doing something others have specialized moves for in Powered by Apocalypse games?

Tags: dungeon-world, powered-by-the-apocalypse

The Apocalypse World and the derived games usually state that if the player **can describe that he's doing something, he does that**.

Unless there is a move for that. If there is a move, and the move is localized in one playbook, the logic gets fuzzy.

But if, for example, the character tries to **bend bars** or **lift gates** in Dungeon World? Can he do that? There is a move for that in the Fighter's playbook, but what if the character in question is a Barbarian? What if that Barbarian has a bigger Str score than the party's Fighter? Will that depend on whether there is a Fighter in the party?

How to handle characters attempting to do something others have specialized moves for?

Answer (score 6):

The logic doesn't really get fuzzy. You just have to trust it.

So either the character just does it (and the logical consequences of that follow), or they trigger a move (but only one they have access to).

An action that would trigger *bend bars or lift gates* (if performed by a Fighter) is likely to trigger *defy danger* if performed by someone else.

You'll notice that the 7-9 result for *defy danger* is much nastier than the 7-9 result for *bend bars or lift gates* … which is why the players would probably much rather have a Fighter attempt it.